# 301 Redirect to remove query string on homepage only

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, magento-2.3

I don't have knowledge of `.htaccess` redirect rules. If a user enters `http://example.com?abc=123` or `https://example.com?who=123` or `https://example.com?xyz=123` then it should redirect to `https://example.com` with a 301 redirect.

If a user enters any query string then it should redirect to the homepage, but I need to implement this only on the homepage not inner, plp or pdp page.

My plp URL is just like `https://example.com/sale.html` and user can add query string on this page via layered navigation filters. We are ok with plp page.

Please help me and provide me `.htaccess` rule or any other way to accomplish this. I am using Magento2 and using Fastly, if anything possible in Magento2 via Fastly then it will easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the query string on any request to the root URL only then add the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
# Remove query string on homepage only
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^$ / [QSD,R=301,L]
```

You do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine On` directive if this already occurs later in the file (which I expect it does).

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* `^$` matches the root only (ie. `https://example.com/`). The preceding *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) checks for the presence of a query string (ie. at least 1 character, denoted by the regex `.`).

If this matches then a 301 (permanent) redirect is triggered back to the root (`/`), but with the query string removed. The `QSD` flag (Query String Discard) removes the original query string from the redirected response.

NB: Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect (ie. change `R=301` to `R=302` in the above `RewriteRule` directive) to avoid potential caching issues. (301s are cached persistently by the browser so can make testing problematic.)